# sum of two-dimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, sum

I try to make a program that sums two-dimensional arrays. The values are preloaded in whole constantees arrangements

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

/*PROGRAM EJERC102 */
const int m1[2][2]={ {3,1},{4,5} };
const int m2[2][2]={ {1,3},{4,2} };
const int m3[2][2];
int f, c;

int main(){
    for (f=0; f <= 1; f++)
         for (c=0; c <= 1; c++)
         {
             m3[f][c]=(m1[f][c] + m2[f][c]); // Why is an assignment of read-only location?
             printf ("(%d,%d)",f,c);
             printf ("%d\n",m3[f][c]);
         }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `const` qualifier from your `m3` declaration?

Comment: @Olaf: How does this invoke undefined behaviour, considering this won't even compile?

Comment: I think the question is in the code itself: `//Why is an assignment of read-only location?`. The answer, well, I'll quote @jacob, 'Try removing the const qualifier from your m3 declaration?'

Comment: @Fang: The fact that it does not compile is because you have a nice compiler which keeps you from compiling it. That does not change the fact it is UB.

Comment: @Olaf: Thanks. I'm in the process of learning C myself, and your comment wasn't quite clear to me.

Comment: @Fang: Just keep the standard under your pillow. Note that the only C standard is ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (or any national number which refers to the international version). Any other version has been withdrawn.

Comment: You are right. It was a silly mistake. If it is constant can not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting an array of const int type, so the main function see it as a read-only values. Just remove the const at the third array declaration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*PROGRAM EJERC102 */
const int m1[2][2]={ {3,1},{4,5} };
const int m2[2][2]={ {1,3},{4,2} };
int m3[2][2];
int f, c;

int main(){
    for (f=0; f <= 1; f++)
        for (c=0; c <= 1; c++)
        {
         m3[f][c]=(m1[f][c] + m2[f][c]); // Why is an assignment of read-only location?
         printf ("(%d,%d)",f,c);
         printf ("%d\n",m3[f][c]);
     }
getchar();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to use the standard getchar() function, instead of getchr of conio.h